# My .py executable or setup file works in my laptop but not in another system

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, windows-installer, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I have created a Python code that uses both `selenium` and `openpyxl`, the code works fine locally. I Converted it into a `.exe` and setup files using `pyinstaller` and it also runs well, but when I transfer it into another computer running on Windows 10 without Python installed, it shows a `Runtime error`. [image: cmd screenshot]

Comment: Hello. The url in the traceback goes [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) Are you on the latest version of numpy? It looks like they have been working on this issue on their [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases). That might fix it. Good luck.

Comment: I can't seem to find the numpy file located in temp folder.I deleted the entire temp folder,installed python on the system,installed numpy 1.19.1 and the program still won't run...

Comment: Trying 1.19.3 or 1.19.4 might fix it.